# Ember: issue when refreshing the index page

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, refresh, ember-cli

When I refresh the index page of my ember app, it appears that I can't call the functions inside my **index.js** file located in **app/routes**.

I don't really know how I can solve this issue.

The source code of **index.js**:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ProjectRoute from 'web/project-route';

export default ProjectRoute.extend({
    authSrv: Ember.inject.service('authentication'),
    _title: 'index.title',
    _requireAuth: true,
    beforeModel()
    {
        "use strict";
        this._super();
    },
    model()
    {
        "use strict";
        console.log(this.get('authSrv').username);
        return {user_id: this.get('authSrv').user_id,
            username: this.get('authSrv').username};
    }
});
```

In the code source above we can see that I try to display the username. When I first log onto this page, it display well, but when I refresh the page, it doesn't display anything.
Any thought about it is welcomed!

Comment: When you refresh the page, you are losing all local state (client side).  The authentication is most likely captured in a session cookie so you remain authenticated after refresh, but any client-side data stored by the authentication process will be lost.

Comment: `doesn't display anything` usually means there is a message of some sort in the console.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from a module that is not up-to-date. I will keep you updated.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't come from a outdated module. I'll check more deeply in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed it with the Ember module RSVP. Basically, the main problem was coming from a promise. I didn't waited to catch the promise.
The **index.js** look like this know.

```js
import Ember from 'ember';
import ProjectRoute from 'web/project-route';

export default ProjectRoute.extend({
    authSrv: Ember.inject.service('authentication'),
    _title: 'index.title',
    _requireAuth: true,
    beforeModel()
    {
        "use strict";
        this._super();
    },
    model()
    {
        "use strict";
        let promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            this.get('authSrv').get('current_auth').promise.then((res) =>
            {
                resolve({user_id: this.get('authSrv').user_id,
                    username: this.get('authSrv').username});
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }
});
```